Amelia WordPress Booking Plugin - Block Out Location Availability for other Employees when Booked for One Employee
I have a two-story clubhouse for rent. Renters can opt to rent upstairs, downstairs, or the full building. If there is someone upstairs, it can be available for another customer to rent downstairs.
Right now, I have my Amelia set up that Upstairs and Downstairs are employees with separate locations & calendars that can be booked by the customer online. But if they want to book the whole clubhouse, they have to call or come in so we can block both levels from the backend to prevent double booking.
Is there a way to create an employee (let's call them Full Building) that is unavailable if Upstairs or Downstairs are booked? And to make Upstairs and Downstairs unavailable if Full Building is booked?
I hope that makes sense. I inherited this website setup from a previous employee and am not a full-time web designer. A lot of times it is very convoluted and I'm not sure if there is an entirely easier way to do this.

More clarity is required.  Most people wont know what Amelia is.  And how is this about websites?  Perhaps post it on Internet of Things site
